# how do i automate creating database in postgresql

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, psql

I'm new to this, can anyone please help me writing a script to automate these lines using shell scripts?

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE testdb;<br>
postgres-#
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on Linux:

1. Login to Linux as `postgresql`
2. Create a file with all your CREATE DATABASE commands. In this example, the file is `createdb.sql` and contains the following 3 create database commands:

   CREATE DATABASE moe;

   CREATE DATABASE larry;

   CREATE DATABASE curly;
3. Run the following from your shell prompt:

   **psql -f createdb.sql**

You can then list your new databases -- in this case, moe, larry and curly.

[image]

Since you mentioned wanting a bash shell script (to automate) the above task, you can create one like follows to accept, as a command-line argument, the name of the SQL (.sql) file that contains your SQL commands, and process them using **psql**:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -f $1
```

Assuming the above file and its contents are called `autosql.sh`, you would change the script mode to execute after it is created (`chmod 755 autosql.sh`) and run it from the command-line as:

```
autosql.sh createdb.sql
```

You can now use this bash shell script and pass in any SQL (.sql) file that contains SQL commands you wish to run.

To automate this process on Linux, use `cron` (see the cron man pages for further information).

Comment: I want CREATE DATABASE TESTDB to be automatically created withot entering from keyboard. sudo -i -u postgres psql after this its entering postgresql here i want that database to be created automatically

Answer (score 2):

Postgres has a command line tool for creating databases: [`createdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html). Your script can call that, and the corresponding [`dropdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-dropdb.html) to drop them.

```
createdb testdb
```

Connection and authentication works very similar to [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). You can either pass your connection information in on the command line, or you can use the environment variables `PGHOST`, `PGPORT`, and `PGUSER`.

For more general commands, you can send commands to Postgres using `psql` by piping them in on stdin.

```
echo 'CREATE DATABASE testdb' | psql
```

For anything more complex, I'd recommend you use a more powerful language with a Postgres database library.